# How to correctly handle Window resizing when using ImGui?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, imgui

I am using ImGui with the aim of creating a Windows Application.

One thing I have noticed and is troubling me a lot is when resizing the Window, it doesn't update the contents (buffers?) correctly, see the attached image:

[image]

The black area was captured whilst I was resizing the window to make it larger.

Here is the exact code I am using that produced the image above:

```
#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#if defined(IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_ES2)
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#endif
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) && !defined(IMGUI_DISABLE_WIN32_FUNCTIONS)
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions")
#endif

GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;

static void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLFW Error %d: %s\n", error, description);
}

void updateBuffers()
{
    ImGui::Render();
    int display_w, display_h;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &display_w, &display_h);
    glViewport(0, 0, display_w, display_h);
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void frame_buffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    const char* glsl_version = "#version 130";
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Dear ImGui GLFW+OpenGL3 example", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
        return 1;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, frame_buffer_size_callback);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;

    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init(glsl_version);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();


        ImGui::Begin("Window");
        ImGui::Text("Hello World!");
        ImGui::End();        

        updateBuffers();
    }

    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I have included the `framebuffer_size_callback()` in order to capture the window during its resize event, but I am unsure what other changes to make. I have come close where I was able to get the Window to resize more nicely simply by calling my draw logic inside the `frame_buffer_size_callback`:

```
void frame_buffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    updateBuffers();
}
```

but the ImGui widgets were getting cut off (this occurs when the widget is slightly offscreen and resizing the window bigger):

[image]

How can I get the Window to resize nicely keeping the ImGui and OpenGL contents drawn correctly too?

Comment: Your window gets recreated and painted every frame (that's kind of the point), so no special action is needed to handle window resizing. You can just remove the code in the callback (and remove the callback too).

Comment: yes I solved it by moving the ImGui draw code into the updateBuffers function

Comment: But did you remove the callback? That's the point of my comment.